# Kafka connect consumer Group ID doesn't set in Fargate cluster

Tags: terraform, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, aws-fargate

I'm using the Debezium PostgreSQL connector to send my PostgreSQL data to Kafka. I set all configs correctly and it's working as expected in the local environment with docker-compose. Then we used Terraform to automate deployment to the AWS Fargate cluster. Terraform scripts also worked fine and launched all the required infrastructures. Then comes the problem;

- The connector doesn't start in Fargate and logs shows `GROUP_ID=1`. ( This is set correctly in local with docker-compose `GROUP_ID=connect-group-dev` )
- I provide the `GROUP_ID` as `connect-group-dev` in environment variables but that is not reflected in to the Fargate cluster container, however in the AWS UI, I can see that `GROUP_ID` is set to `connect-group-dev`.
- All other environment variables are reflected in to the container.

I suspect the problem is that `GROUP_ID` is not getting by the container when it's starting the Kafka Connector, but in a later step, it is set to the container. ( because I can see the correct value in AWS UI in the Task Definition )

Is the default value is `1` for `GROUP_ID`? (since I don't set any variable to `1` )

This is a weird situation and double-check all the files, but still cannot find a reason for this. Any help would be great.

Comment: I changed the base image to the confluent base image from the debezium one and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use MSK Connect rather than Fargate, but assuming you are using Debezium Docker container, then yes [`GROUP_ID=1` is the default](https://github.com/debezium/container-images/blob/main/connect-base/2.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L32)

If you are *not* using Debezium container, then that would explain why the variable is not set at runtime.